# Xamarin Forms: Carousel child pages not firing Disappearing event?

Tags: xamarin.forms, carousel, ondisappearing

I have a Carousel page having 9 children and I have implemented a tracking feature on some of the child pages. The tracking feature is for video, audio and content. If a user plays a video, audio, or read content and then the user moves to the next child or going back to the previous page at that time I will track the spent time.

I have added the tracking service on the `OnDisappearing()` of child pages. So when a user leaves a page the tracking service starts triggering and it is working fine on the android platform. When I test it on the ios platform, the `OnDisappearing()` is not firing.

Is it a known issue? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you use some third party library ? You could share your sample .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I am not using any third-party library, I will share a sample soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Event **OnDisappearing** works fine on my side both on iOS and Android . If the issue still exist on your project . You could use the following workaround .

#### in xaml

```
<CarouselPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CarouselPageDemo"
             x:Class="CarouselPageDemo.MyCarouselPage"

              CurrentPageChanged="CarouselPage_CurrentPageChanged">
```

#### in CarouselPage.xaml.cs

```
 int CurrentIndex = 0;

//...

    private void CarouselPage_CurrentPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var index = this.Children.IndexOf(this.CurrentPage);

 

        var ind = CurrentIndex.ToString();

 

        if (index != CurrentIndex)
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send<Object>(this, ind);
        }

 

        if (index > -1)
        {
            CurrentIndex = index;
        }

 

    }
```

#### in child page

```
public Page1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

 

  MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object>(this, "0", (org) =>
  {

 
     //   ... handle the logic when the page will disappearing

  });
}
```

**Note :**  the **0** here will different in your child pages (0,1,2,...)

### Update

```
    public partial class MainPage : CarouselPage
    {


        int LastIndex=0;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Children.Add(new Page1());
            this.Children.Add(new Page2());
            this.Children.Add(new Page3());
            CurrentPage = Children[0];

            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, string>((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "child", (s, child) =>
            {
                CurrentPage = Children[Int32.Parse(child)];
            });
        }

        private void CarouselPage_CurrentPageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var index = this.Children.IndexOf(this.CurrentPage);
            string title = this.CurrentPage.Title;
            Debug.WriteLine("title:>>" + title);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(title)&& LastIndex!=index)
            {
                MessagingCenter.Send<MainPage>(this, title);
            }

            if (index > -1)
            {
                LastIndex = index;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use the index property, because the number of children will vary in my case. So I tried to implement the same using title property. But no luck, is it possible to implement the same using title of child page? string title = this.CurrentPage.Title;

Comment: You can add a custom property in each ContentPage .

Comment: Sorry, your answer is not helping. This will only trigger the new page subscribe part. I am trying to trigger the page which is disappearing.

Comment: I have created a sample, could you please check that? If I move the pages by scrolling it will trigger the ondisappearing(). If I click the collectioview item, the ondisappearing() is not firing. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aJVIx8MbwsVGguSsfJadpDSWCFAzVLUJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The issue is only on the ios part, android part is working fine

Comment: I have created a new sample using this solution. But it only opens the new page subscribe function, I need to fire the page which is disappearing. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KOtPKi8BGyvavekjqKdYgzddeN7JPgE8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The solution is different with mine , check my code in method CarouselPage_CurrentPageChanged , set the property CurrentIndex  to save last page .

Comment: I have tested the updated answer, but it is hitting the new page subscribe part, not the old page. If I move from page 1 to page 2, I need to fire the page 1 Subscribe method. Currently, it is hitting the page2 Subscribe method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221197/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-sreejith-sree).